# Installing PATCH_SUPEE-7405 for CE 1.9.1.0 returns an error

Tags: patches

I installed all patches before 7405, but when I check app/etc/applied.patches.list, somehow it shows patch 5344 installed for EE magento version (SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1), and when I attempt to install patch 7405 I get an error that I uploaded the image of it!

it seems the error coming from Observes.php but I'm not sure what is Observer.php.rej, which I cannot find this file anywhere in the server.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

[image]

Observer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Admin
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Admin observer model
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Admin
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Admin_Model_Observer
{
    const FLAG_NO_LOGIN = 'no-login';
    /**
     * Handler for controller_action_predispatch event
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function actionPreDispatchAdmin($observer)
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $user = $session->getUser();

        $requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
        $openActions = array(
            'forgotpassword',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'logout',
            'refresh' // captcha refresh
        );
        if (in_array($requestedActionName, $openActions)) {
            $request->setDispatched(true);
        } else {
            if($user) {
                $user->reload();
            }
            if (!$user || !$user->getId()) {
                if ($request->getPost('login')) {
                    $postLogin  = $request->getPost('login');
                    $username   = isset($postLogin['username']) ? $postLogin['username'] : '';
                    $password   = isset($postLogin['password']) ? $postLogin['password'] : '';
                    $session->login($username, $password, $request);
                    $request->setPost('login', null);
                }
                if (!$request->getParam('forwarded')) {
                    if ($request->getParam('isIframe')) {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('deniedIframe')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    } elseif($request->getParam('isAjax')) {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('deniedJson')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    } else {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setRouteName('adminhtml')
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('login')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        $session->refreshAcl();
    }

    /**
     * Unset session first visit flag after displaying page
     *
     * @deprecated after 1.4.0.1, logic moved to admin session
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $event
     */
    public function actionPostDispatchAdmin($event)
    {
    }
}
```

Code related to Observer.php in patch:

```
__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
index 9c04324..9d39424 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
@@ -34,6 +34,7 @@
 class Mage_Admin_Model_Observer
 {
     const FLAG_NO_LOGIN = 'no-login';
+
     /**
      * Handler for controller_action_predispatch event
      *
@@ -42,16 +43,14 @@ class Mage_Admin_Model_Observer
      */
     public function actionPreDispatchAdmin($observer)
     {
-        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
         /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
+        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

-        /**
-         * @var $request Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http
-         */
+        /** @var $request Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http */
         $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
         $user = $session->getUser();

-        $requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
+        $requestedActionName = strtolower($request->getActionName());
         $openActions = array(
             'forgotpassword',
             'resetpassword',
@@ -67,11 +66,26 @@ class Mage_Admin_Model_Observer
             }
             if (!$user || !$user->getId()) {
                 if ($request->getPost('login')) {
-                    $postLogin  = $request->getPost('login');
-                    $username   = isset($postLogin['username']) ? $postLogin['username'] : '';
-                    $password   = isset($postLogin['password']) ? $postLogin['password'] : '';
-                    $session->login($username, $password, $request);
-                    $request->setPost('login', null);
+
+                    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Session $coreSession */
+                    $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
+
+                    if ($coreSession->validateFormKey($request->getPost("form_key"))) {
+                        $postLogin = $request->getPost('login');
+                        $username = isset($postLogin['username']) ? $postLogin['username'] : '';
+                        $password = isset($postLogin['password']) ? $postLogin['password'] : '';
+                        $session->login($username, $password, $request);
+                        $request->setPost('login', null);
+                    } else {
+                        if ($request && !$request->getParam('messageSent')) {
+                            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
+                                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.')
+                            );
+                            $request->setParam('messageSent', true);
+                        }
+                    }
+
+                    $coreSession->renewFormKey();
                 }
                 if (!$request->getInternallyForwarded()) {
                     $request->setInternallyForwarded();
```

Comment: Can you output here code of your version of Observer.php and text from patch which refers to this observer?

Comment: Did you apply the previous patches ?

Comment: I don't know proper way how to determine which changes from which patch were not applied to some magento. If this variant will be suitable for you - we can apply patch manually for this file and remove from the patch changes for this file. If you like it - I can prepare file for you.

Comment: Looks like you have no another way to do it manually or you need to revert back patch applied for EE.

Comment: ya I checked app/etc/applied.patches.list, the only problem is, in applied.patches.list, SUPEE-5344 installed for EE_1.14.1.0, the first line of applied.patches.list is SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1, the others all installed I guess! Do you want me to get the screen shot from applied.patches.list ?

Comment: which way is easier to be done, revert back the patch applied for EE or do it manually ? is it possible to help me that how can I revert back the patch already installed?

Comment: Only if your magento is under Git or another version control system.

Comment: Unfortunately is not!

Comment: I think the most easiest way for you will be patch Observer manually and modify patch.sh. Do you need any help with patch apply?

Comment: ya will appreciate if you can help me with that, cause I'm not that familiar how to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace your Observer with this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Admin
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Admin observer model
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Admin
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Admin_Model_Observer
{
    const FLAG_NO_LOGIN = 'no-login';

    /**
     * Handler for controller_action_predispatch event
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function actionPreDispatchAdmin($observer)
    {
        /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

        /** @var $request Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http */
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $user = $session->getUser();

        $requestedActionName = strtolower($request->getActionName());
        $openActions = array(
            'forgotpassword',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'logout',
            'refresh' // captcha refresh
        );
        if (in_array($requestedActionName, $openActions)) {
            $request->setDispatched(true);
        } else {
            if ($user) {
                $user->reload();
            }
            if (!$user || !$user->getId()) {
                if ($request->getPost('login')) {

                    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Session $coreSession */
                    $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

                    if ($coreSession->validateFormKey($request->getPost("form_key"))) {
                        $postLogin = $request->getPost('login');
                        $username = isset($postLogin['username']) ? $postLogin['username'] : '';
                        $password = isset($postLogin['password']) ? $postLogin['password'] : '';
                        $session->login($username, $password, $request);
                        $request->setPost('login', null);
                    } else {
                        if ($request && !$request->getParam('messageSent')) {
                            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.')
                            );
                            $request->setParam('messageSent', true);
                        }
                    }

                    $coreSession->renewFormKey();
                }
                if (!$request->getInternallyForwarded()) {
                    $request->setInternallyForwarded();
                    if ($request->getParam('isIframe')) {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('deniedIframe')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    } elseif ($request->getParam('isAjax')) {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('deniedJson')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    } else {
                        $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                            ->setRouteName('adminhtml')
                            ->setControllerName('index')
                            ->setActionName('login')
                            ->setDispatched(false);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        $session->refreshAcl();
    }

    /**
     * Unset session first visit flag after displaying page
     *
     * @deprecated after 1.4.0.1, logic moved to admin session
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $event
     */
    public function actionPostDispatchAdmin($event)
    {
    }
}
```

And remove from patch everything which refers to Observer.php (most likely  everything you posted in your question).

After patch to determine if everything is working fine try to authorize as admin.

Comment: I did as you said, its working ! thanks for your help :)